# dojo1.8 - position a instantiated select widget on the canvas and populate it with options

Tags: dojo

Please see my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/pzAcm/75/)

I have set and instantiate the select bus was unable to fill with options.
Also  I am not sure how to position the widget in the canvas.

```
var response1 = [{
    "test": "Mk7ABC Card",
    "use": "lit"
}, {
    "test": "Mk7CBC Card",
    "use": "lit"
}, {
    "test": "Mk10BC Card",
    "use": "lit"
}, {
    "test": "Mk7CBC Card",
    "use": "dim"
}]

var memoStore1 = new Memory({
    data: response1
});

declare("buildSelect", [_WidgetBase], {
    buildRendering: function () {
        this.domNode = domConstruct.create("select", {})
    }
});

 new buildSelect({
        id: "selectTest",
        store: memoStore1,
        searchAttr: "test"
    }).placeAt(dom.byId('mfg_codeSelect'));
```

Thanks in advance
Clement

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that jump out at me:

- You are extending _WidgetBase, but it sounds like you want to extend dijit/form/Select
- You are overriding buildRendering() and not allowing the parent class's buildRendering() to run. You probably want to do something like this:

  ```
  buildRendering: function () {
      this.domNode = domConstruct.create("select", {})
      this.inherited(arguments);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Jeremiah. The reason I wanted to code this, is because I wanted to create an object and then destroy it after populating with a set of options, then again  build and populate with another set of items.